# ¿Como utilizar una variable de entorno definida en el sistema en ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, windows, variables

Por ejemplo, si tengo una variable de entorno definida en el sistema :
[image: Variable de entorno del sistema]

¿Puedo llamarla desde ReactJS y leer su valor ?

Answer (score 3):

No, no puedes. Si lo que quieres es detectar en qué entorno se está ejecutando una aplicación, lo tienes que hacer de otro modo. El navegador no tiene acceso a información del sistema de este tipo porque sería un grave problema de privacidad.